# cgo: Go pointers in Go memory

Tags: go, cgo

Does the code:

```
unsafe.Pointer(&du)
```

where `du` is some `interface` satisfy the rule 1 from the following list?

https://github.com/golang/go/issues/12416

> Go code may pass a Go pointer to C provided that the Go memory to
>   which it points does not contain any Go pointers. That rule must be
>   preserved during C execution, in that the program must not store any
>   Go pointers into that memory.

In other words, is the C-pointer to Go `interface` considered as a "pointer to Go memory containing a Go pointers"?

**UPDATE:**

My issue is the following code:

```
type Receiver interface {
    Signal()
}

func WowFunction(data []byte, du Receiver) {

    C.wow_function( (*C.char)( unsafe.Pointer(&data[0]) ), 
                    (C.size_t)(len(data)),
                    unsafe.Pointer(&du))    // this is my suspect
}
```

My idea is to make C-code calling the `Receiver`'s "method" `Signal()`. I achieve this by exporting a Go-callback and passing that `&du` as an argument to the callback:

```
//export go_callback
func go_callback(object_ptr unsafe.Pointer) {

    object := *(*Receiver)(object_ptr);
    object.Signal()
}
```

Is there another way to reach that?

Comment: yes, a pointer to an interface is considered "pointer to Go memory containing a Go pointers", but what valid use could there be to pass a pointer to a Go interface into C?

Comment: @JimB see the update to my post. I put a description of why I need that.

Comment: is the `&du` in `unsafe.Pointer(&du))    // this is my suspect` supposed to be `&de`?

Comment: `du` isn't even declared, so this can't compile in the first place. But in the end, an interface contains 2 pointer values, so cgo isn't going to allow you to pass a pointer to an interface, even if there were a way to make it work.

Comment: @JimB "du" == "de". Thank you.

Comment: There is some example code in the [cgo wiki page](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/cgo) for callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer

In follow up to @JimB, yes, this is considered a pointer to Go memory containing a Go pointer, so in go >= 1.6 you're going to get "cgo argument has Go pointer to Go pointer" panics when you run your program.

If you want to use something like this at runtime, you can disable the panic by running your program with `GODEBUG=cgocheck=0`.

I've actually written code like this before in go < 1.6 to wrap object-oriented handler code that's called asynchronously from threaded C code--so I don't think the use-case is that crazy.

#### Alternatives

One possible alternative to passing the pointer directly to the underlying C code is to make a threadsafe global registry for your handlers, so you would basically pass some index to the registry into the C code, receive it back in your callback, look up the handler for that index and then invoke the function on it.

---

### Examples

These are a bit lengthy, but give an actual working example. If you want to just take a look at the registry implementation example, jump to the bottom.

#### Direct Pointer Example (Your issue)

Not the best C in the world, but here's a quick simplification of other code I've done this with before

**Library Code**

Makefile:

```
libtesting:
  gcc -fPIC -c library/testing.c -o library/testing.o
  gcc -dynamiclib library/testing.o -o library/libtesting.dylib
```

C Header:

```
/* library/testing.h */

#ifndef __TESTING_H__
#define __TESTING_H__

#include <pthread.h>

struct worker_node {
  pthread_t worker;
  struct worker_node *next;
};

// Structs for publisher
struct publisher {
  void (* callback)(void *, char *, int);
  void *context;
  struct worker_node *workers;
};

struct publisher * publisher_new(void *, void (*)(void *, char *, int));
void publisher_cleanup(struct publisher *);
void publisher_finish(struct publisher *);
void publisher_publish(struct publisher *, char *, int);

#endif // __TESTING_H__
```

C Source:

```
/* library/testing.c */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

#include "testing.h"

struct message_wrapper {
  void * context;
  char * message;
  int message_len;
  void (* callback)(void *, char *, int);
};

struct publisher * publisher_new(void *context, void (*callback)(void *, char *, int)) {
  struct publisher * self = (struct publisher *)malloc(sizeof(struct publisher));
  assert(self);
  assert(self->callback = callback);
  self->context = context;
  self->workers = NULL;

  return self;
}

void publisher_cleanup(struct publisher * self) {
  struct worker_node * next_node;
  struct worker_node * node = self->workers;
  while (node != NULL) {
    next_node = node->next;
    free(node);
    node = next_node;
  }
  free(self);
  self = NULL;
}

static void * publisher_worker_thread(void * args) {
  struct message_wrapper * wrapper = (struct message_wrapper *)args;

  wrapper->callback(wrapper->context, wrapper->message, wrapper->message_len);

  free(wrapper->message);
  free(wrapper);

  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void publisher_publish(struct publisher *self, char * message, int message_len) {
  pthread_attr_t attr;

  pthread_attr_init(&attr);
  pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);

  struct worker_node * new_node = (struct worker_node *)malloc(sizeof(struct worker_node));
  new_node->next = self->workers;
  self->workers = new_node;

  struct message_wrapper *wrapper = (struct message_wrapper *)malloc(sizeof(struct message_wrapper));
  wrapper->message = malloc(message_len);
  memcpy(wrapper->message, message, message_len);
  wrapper->message_len = message_len;
  wrapper->context = self->context;
  wrapper->callback = self->callback;

  assert(!pthread_create(&self->workers->worker, &attr, publisher_worker_thread, (void *)wrapper));
}

void publisher_finish(struct publisher *self) {
  struct worker_node * node = self->workers;
  while (node != NULL) {
    assert(!pthread_join(node->worker, NULL));
    node = node->next;
  }
}
```

**Go Code**

C wrapper:

```
/* testing_c.c */

#include "_cgo_export.h"

void cgo_callback_wrapper(void * context, char *message, int message_len) {
    callbackWrapper(context, message, message_len);
}
```

Go:

```
package main

/*
#cgo LDFLAGS: -lpthread -Llibrary -ltesting
#include "library/testing.h"

extern void cgo_callback_wrapper(void * context, char *message, int message_len);
*/
import "C"

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

type Handler interface {
    HandleMessage([]byte)
}

type Publisher struct {
    base *C.struct_publisher
}

//export callbackWrapper
func callbackWrapper(cContext unsafe.Pointer, cMessage *C.char, cMessageSize C.int) {
    handler := *(*Handler)(cContext)
    message := C.GoBytes(unsafe.Pointer(cMessage), cMessageSize)
    handler.HandleMessage(message)
}

func (p *Publisher) Publish(message []byte) {
    cMessage := (*C.char)(unsafe.Pointer(&message[0]))
    cMessageLen := C.int(len(message))
    C.publisher_publish(p.base, cMessage, cMessageLen)
}

func CreatePublisher(handler Handler) *Publisher {
    return &Publisher{
        base: C.publisher_new(unsafe.Pointer(&handler), (*[0]byte)(C.cgo_callback_wrapper)),
    }
}

func (p *Publisher) Finish() {
    C.publisher_finish(p.base)
}

//////// EXAMPLE ////////

type TestHandler struct {
    name string
}

func (h TestHandler) HandleMessage(message []byte) {
    fmt.Printf("%s received %v", h.name, message)
}

func main() {
    handler := TestHandler{name: "Test"}

    publisher := CreatePublisher(handler)
    publisher.Publish([]byte("test"))
    publisher.Finish()
}
```

Disregard not cleaning up memory allocations...

If you put the go, c wrappers, and Makefile in the top-level directory, the "C library" in a folder named library and run `make && go build` (on OS X, adjust the makefile compiler flags for Linux) you should get a panic of "cgo argument has Go pointer to Go pointer" using go >= 1.6 and no panic for go < 1.6 when running the binary. Building with go 1.6 and running with `GODEBUG=cgocheck=0` should output `Test received [116 101 115 116]`.

#### Registry Example (Alternative)

To make this example run under 1.6 without disabling `cgocheck` add a registry kind of like this:

```
package main

/*
#cgo LDFLAGS: -lpthread -Llibrary -ltesting
#include "library/testing.h"

extern void cgo_callback_wrapper(void * context, char *message, int message_len);
*/
import "C"

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "unsafe"
)

var registry map[int]Handler
var handlers int
var mutex = sync.Mutex{}

type Handler interface {
    HandleMessage([]byte)
}

type Publisher struct {
    base *C.struct_publisher
}

//export callbackWrapper
func callbackWrapper(cContext unsafe.Pointer, cMessage *C.char, cMessageSize C.int) {
    mutex.Lock()
    handler := registry[*(*int)(cContext)]
    mutex.Unlock()
    message := C.GoBytes(unsafe.Pointer(cMessage), cMessageSize)
    handler.HandleMessage(message)
}

func (p *Publisher) Publish(message []byte) {
    cMessage := (*C.char)(unsafe.Pointer(&message[0]))
    cMessageLen := C.int(len(message))
    C.publisher_publish(p.base, cMessage, cMessageLen)
}

func CreatePublisher(handler Handler) *Publisher {
    mutex.Lock()
    index := handlers
    handlers++
    if registry == nil {
        registry = make(map[int]Handler)
    }
    registry[index] = handler
    mutex.Unlock()
    return &Publisher{
        base: C.publisher_new(unsafe.Pointer(&index), (*[0]byte)(C.cgo_callback_wrapper)),
    }
}

func (p *Publisher) Finish() {
    C.publisher_finish(p.base)
}

//////// EXAMPLE ////////

type TestHandler struct {
    name string
}

func (h TestHandler) HandleMessage(message []byte) {
    fmt.Printf("%s received %v", h.name, message)
}

func main() {
    handler := TestHandler{name: "Test"}

    publisher := CreatePublisher(handler)
    publisher.Publish([]byte("test"))
    publisher.Finish()
}
```

Notice the addition of registry code in `CreatePublisher` and `callbackWrapper` and now instead of passing a pointer to an interface we now just pass a pointer to the index of the interface in the registry. Compile the same way and no more panics!

Comment: Just FYI, in case you were wondering where my use-case cropped up, it's a go wrapper to a high-level kafka library written in C that wraps librdkafka and heavily relies on callbacks and passing context.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another hacky to workaround this. It is not encouraged unless the content of whatever is passing around is not accessed by your C library (like C library only pass it around for callbacks).

Idea is to cast your unsafe.Pointer to C.ulonglong

Calling C

```
C.function(C.ulonglong(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&something))))
```

Casting it back

```
(*SomethingType)(unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(the_c_long_value)))
```